# How to fetch all subcollections documents from array of document-ids in firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am building javascript service where I want to fetch all subcollections document details from firestore from the input of **"collection name"** and **"document-id arrays"**.

Request payload invoking my service:

```
{
root_collection_name: "root_collection",
"msgId": ['11','22','33','66'],
"subcollection_name": "message"
}
```

I need to search for all **subcollection**(common name for all documents) documents for all this **msgId's**.

My firestore structure looks as below

```
collection:
    document1:
        subcollection:
            document:
                "val1":"red",
                "val2":"blue",
                "val3":"green"
    document2:
        subcollection:
            document:
                "val1":"apple",
                "val2":"mango",
                "val3":"grape"
    document3:
        ..............
            ................
```

example:

```
root_collection:
    11:
        aaa:
            message:
                "val1":"red",
                "val2":"blue",
                "val3":"green"
    22:
        bbb:
            message:
                "val1":"apple",
                "val2":"mango",
                "val3":"grape"
```

In this scenario i need to fetch data for **msgId** **"11"**, **"22"** which is available in firestore and other values should send null. Could you please help on this not sure where I am missing here.

Here is the code I wrote for this.

```
const input = {
"root_collection_name": "root_collection",
"msgId": ['11','22','33','66'],
"subcollection_name": "message"
}
    

const test =  (input) => {
    const query = firestore.collection(input.root_collection_name).where('id', 'array-contains-any', input.msgId);
      query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
          document.ref.collection(input.subcollection_name).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              console.log('doc data',doc.data());
            });
          });
        });
      }); 
    };

test(input);
```

Comment: From what I understand, you want to display the documents along with its fields "val" using the payload you've provided. If so, could you please update and include how you're calling these payload input on your code? This will help the community replicate your program without having to spend too much time to make your code work on their environment.

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo you are right  I need to fetch "val" fields using the input payload added in the above code. Kindly let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add your top-level document's ID into the subcollection documents, then you could [use collectionGroup](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html).

So, from your example you would have:

```
root_collection:
11:
    aaa:
        message:
            "root_id": "11", // <<-- new!
            "val1":"red",
            "val2":"blue",
            "val3":"green"
22:
    bbb:
        message:
            "root_id": "22", // <<-- new!
            "val1":"apple",
            "val2":"mango",
            "val3":"grape"
```

and you could query with:

```
var msgs = firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('message')
             .where('root_id', 'in', ['11','22']);
```

CAUTION: this would query any and all subcollections named `message`.  As you add newer subcollections to your model, you might choose a different name if they are not the same type of "message".

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Greg. I do have top-level document-id in the sub-collection document, but its present under array of attributes as mentioned below comment.

Comment: root_collection:
11:
    aaa:
        message:
   **"root_elm":[
   "root_name":"name1",
                         "root_id": "11"
   ],**
            "val1":"red",
            "val2":"blue",
            "val3":"green"
22:
    bbb:
        message:
  **"root_elm":[
   "root_name":"name2",
                        "root_id": "22"
   ], **
            "val1":"apple",
            "val2":"mango",
            "val3":"grape"


Could you please suggest how to handle this kind of scenario in firestore querying?

Comment: I don't understand the "root_elm" nodes.  [ "xx":"yy", "zz": "ww"] is not valid JSON.  Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry. its array of objects. I have corrected and updated structure below. 
root_collection: 11: aaa: message: **"root_elm":[{"root_name":"name1", "root_id": "11" }]**, "val1":"red", "val2":"blue", "val3":"green" 22: bbb: message: **"root_elm":[{ "root_name":"name2", "root_id": "22"} ]**, "val1":"apple", "val2":"mango", "val3":"grape"
Also Could you please let me know whether do we need to have indexing enabled for searching elements ?

Comment: firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('message').where('root_elm.root_id', 'in', ['11', '22']);